# Completeness of the union

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I want to prove
if $M_1, M_2 \subset N$ are complete, then $M_1 \cup M_2$ is complete.

I was trying taking an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $M_1 \cup M_2$, and trying to find a convergent subsequence in $M_1$ or $M_2$:
If $(x_n)\subset M_1 \cup M_2$ is a Cauchy sequence, wlog there exists $(x_{n_k})\subset M_1$, this is a Cauchy subsequence. (Is this right?). But $M_1$ is complete, then $(x_{n_k})\to x \in M_1$. Then $(x_n)\to x \in M_1 \subset M_1 \cup M_2$. 
As $(x_n)$ was an arbitrary Cauchy sequence, we can conclude that $M_1 \cup M_2$ is complete.

Someone can help? Is the first time I try to do this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumming N is not the natural numbers, which would not be complete.

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in one of the set M$_1$ or M$_2$.  Choose M$_1$ without loss of generality.  The $\{p_n\}\subset M_1$.  Since M$_1$ is complete, $\{p_n\}$ converges to a point of M$_1$.  M$_1\subset M_1\cup M_2$.  Thus $\{p_n\}$ converges to a point of $M_1\cup M_2$.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was if the subequence was Cauchy or not, but it must be.

Comment: If the sets are complete, then every Cauchy sequence converges to a point in that set.  So you can choose an arbitrary Cauchy sequence and you know it converges.  If that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Given a Cauchy sequence in $M_1\cup M_2$, it must have infinitely many (not necessarily distinct) terms in $M_1$ or infinitely many in $M_2$, because if it had only finitely many terms in each then it would have only finitely many terms altogether.  So suppose it has infinitely many terms in $M_i$. Those terms constitute a Cauchy sequence, because they're a subsequence of the original Cauchy sequence.  So this subsequence converges to some point in $M_i$, because $M_i$ is complete.  But then the whole original sequence converges to the same point, because a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence is always convergent (regardless of any completeness assumptions).

Comment: what happens if both $M_1$ and $M_2$ has infinitely many terms of the original sequence? Like: all even terms are in $M_1$ and all odd are in $M_2$? Both of them certainly would constitute subsequences of the original one, and since $M_1$ and $M_2$ are complete, both subsequences would converge in $M_1$ and $M_2$, respectively. Now, we are getting two convergent subsequences of a Cauchy sequence. Therefore they must converge into the same limit. But what if $M_1\cap M_2 = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: @math.h You've proved in your comment that the two subsequences converge to limits $l_1$ and $l_2$ that (1) are in $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively and (2) are equal to each other. From those facts it follows that $M_1\cap M_2\neq\emptyset$. (Details: $l_1\in M_1$. Also $l_1\in M_2$ because $l_1=l_2$ and $l_2\in M_2$. So $l_1\in M_1\cap M_2$.)